# Preliminaries to BPV's compact complex surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Where can I find a quick introduction to topological and analytic preliminaries to
"Compact complex surfaces" by W. Barth, K. Hulek, C. Peters and A. Van de Ven？ Thanks for any references or comments.

Comment: 1) If people refer to books or papers by their authors' initials, MO becomes totally unreadable. Please write out the proper reference for the book (I presume it is "Compact complex surfaces" by Barth, Peters Van de Ven and, in the second edition, Hulek.)

Comment: 2) What specifically do you want to know about?

Comment: Dear Tim, you are right. I need some topological background such as why the singular cohomology coincides with the sheaf cohomology. Thanks for diverrietti's edit.

Comment: I don't have access to my books right now, but I believe Spanier's *Algebraic topology*, or Warner's *Foundations of differentiable manifolds* would contain a proof of the comparison. 